# Programmatically check the checkbox of an exposed filter

Tags: views, 8

I need to check a checkbox on an exposed filter for a view based on the url. I can't seem to figure out how to do that. If x is detected in the url, I want to set one of the fields of an exposed filter to have the status checked="checked." It seems like that would be pretty easy, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have tried various ways through:

- `hook_views_pre_view()`
- `hook_views_pre_build()`
- `hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter()` (I feel like this should be the best way.)

I've found that I can effectively alter the results through `hook_views_pre_view()`, but I can't figure out how to check that freaking checkbox on the exposed filter.

Varioush failed attempts via `hook_form_alter()`:

- `$form["field_intended_use_target_id"]["#default_value"] = ['357'];`
- `$form_state->input["field_intended_use_target_id"][356] = '356';`
- `$form['field_intended_use_target_id']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = ['357'];`

Can anyone please help?

Comment: try `['#default_value'] = 357;` since value is not an array.

Comment: btw don't add single `''` nor `""` double quotes around numbers, because when you do that, you're making them "strings" type rather than "numeric".

Comment: No luck. Using xdebug I can see that it does in fact set the default value. But it still doesn't render with the checkbox checked. I checked source to confirm. I turned off my theme and used Bartik. Still no dice.

Comment: Also tried removing quotes. Just can't seem to get that checked attribute for anything.

Comment: I suggest you add a default value on your view's exposed filter settings, then check how the structure looks like, find where exactly the `['#default_value']` gets added inside `$form` array. Then you'll know where you need to put it.

Comment: Well, that was a good idea to at least rule out some stuff. `$form["field_intended_use_target_id"]["#default_value"][357] = 357` is the right way to set it. But It must be too late by the time it hits hook_form_views_exposed_form_alter. Because even though I can see that I'm resetting it from 358 (the test deafult) to 357 (the id I want) perfectly via xdebug, the other value (358) is still the one that shows up checked. I can't alter it. I guess this needs to be done in some other hook?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100890/discussion-between-no-sssweat-and-xpersonas).

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to achieve what I need via the hook_views_pre_build() hook.

Please let me know if this is wrong or if there is a better way, but from what I can tell this is the best way to achieve this.

```
function module_views_pre_build(ViewExecutable $view) {
  $termId = 357;
  $view->setExposedInput(['field_name' => [$termId => $termId]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hook_form_alter()` by adding view id condition.
The use the code below, replacing `FILTER_NAME` with the name of your filter and set the necessary options.

```
$request = \Drupal::request();
if (!$request->get(FILTER_NAME, NULL)) {
  $input = &$form_state->getUserInput();
  $input[FILTER_NAME] = [
    'opt1' => 'opt1',
    'opt2' => 'opt2',
  ];
}
```